# MRC Compression from PDFs with iText or iTextSharp

Tags: c#, compression, itext

We're developing an application that operates with a lot of PDF-Files (viewing, editing, creating, archiving, ...).

Currently we're facing disk space issues when saving thousand of files in the PDF/A standard (including fonts, references, ...). Therefore we're evaluating different approaches to minimize the required space to persist all the documents.

One option on our list is called Mixed Raster Content (MRC) compression.

Does anyone knows if iText or iTextSharp supports MRC compression and point up a hint where I can find some documentation how to utlize the library for that purpose?

Comment: AFAIK iText does not have such optimization ready-to-use. On the other hand iText offers the low level routines allowing you to manipulate PDFs in arbitrary ways. Are you sure, though, that your documents can be reasonably compressed like that at all? After all PDF already is a mixed raster/vector/template format...

Comment: To further what @mkl said, MRC happens at the image level, not the PDF level. Any PDF processor out there that says that they do MRC really means that they will extract your images, alter them and put them back into the PDF. That _alter_ is the important part and that's something that iText won't do. Also, to get _awesome_ compression you need to use lossy/destructive techniques and iText only deals with lossless/non-destructive techniques.